# Difference between two classes as objects in python

Tags: python, class, object

In python class is an object. When I create a class like this -

```
class example1:
    pass:
```

and then print the class object I get this -

```
print example1
__main__.example1
```

But when I create a class as a subclass of Object class -

```
class example2(object):
    pass:
```

and then print the class object I get this -

```
print example2
<class '__main__.example2'>
```

Why is there a difference between two representations of class objects?What is exactly **main** in both the cases?

Comment: And now do the same, but using Python 3 instead...

Comment: As for `__main__`, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/3001761, https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html - and please ask one question at a time.